# How do you select multiple files in Ubuntu Touch file manager?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, filemanager

On BQ4.5, OTA11, file manager v.0.4.543. I can´t find a way to select multiple files to copy, cut, delete etc. I´m able to do that with a single file....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to select multiple files.  There are bug reports about it. This one is a current wishlist item.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1587499

Add yourself to it.

Comment: Done & yes wishlist item sounds better than a bug :-) thank you